# Display dropdown list user as a first result based on URL ID along with the other users

Tags: php, laravel

I have a dropdown with a list of users and I need to know how to display the username based on URL id as a first result along with the other users

`https://my.space/profiel/50`

```
 $user = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->id())->get();

        return view('profile.list', compact(''user',$user));
```

For Example  :

```
User ID 50 = James Franco
```

if the *URL ID 50* In the Dropdown  first result should be James Franco IF the *URL ID 25 Dropdown* list first result should be *Johnny Deff* and I already write the code below to not loading the *Auth User* in the dropdown.

```
   <select>
      <option value ="50" >James Franco</option>
      <option value ="45">Amy Adams</option>
      <option value ="25">Jhonny Deff</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: so you need to make the selected option based on the url

Answer (score 1):

As you are showing the profile with user id. You can simply compare your user id with dropdown users id.You can pass id and match with the dropdown.

```
<select>
      <option value ="50" @if($user->id== 50) selected @endif >James Franco</option>
      <option value ="45">Amy Adams</option>
      <option value ="25">Jhonny Deff</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the controller:

(result of query must be an array)
this is your url id that you are going to display first on the dropdown
'id' => 50,
'name' => 'Jhonny Deff'

Example:

> This is the data that you are going to display on top:

```
$first_data = array(
        'id' => 50,
        'name' => 'Jhonny Deff'
    );
```

> This is your dropdownlist

```
$dropdownlist = [
        0 => array(
                'id' => 51,
                'name' => 'James Franco'
            ),
        1 => array(
                'id' => 52,
                'name' => 'Amy Adams'
            ),
    ];
```

> Insert array data on TOP

```
array_unshift($dropdownlist , $first_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer in your question but may I ask why you want to do that? You can always have the id as selected in select option by doing `$('#selectID').val('ValueYouWantToSelect');`

Answer (score 0):

It's simple add the user manually at top of the list

```
$user = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->id())->get();
```

```
 <select>
      <option value ="{{ auth()->id() }}" selected>{{ auth()->user()->name }}</option>
      <option value ="45">Amy Adams</option>
      <option value ="25">Jhonny Deff</option>
    </select>
```

to show other users:

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->id())->get();
```

```
 <select>
      <option value ="{{ auth()->id() }}" selected>{{ auth()->user()->name }}</option>
@foreach($users as $user)
      <option value ="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
@endforeach
      
    </select>
```